# list comprehension with iteration

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Suppose i have a list L which consists of integer elements. I want to construct a list T which for each index i in 0..len(L) contains the item L[i]  provided it is larger than 0 using List comprehension in python.

I tried the following command to do this

```
T=[L[i] if L[i]>0 for i in range(len(L))]
```

but i keep getting an error of invalid syntax. How would i do this correctly using List comprehensions in python?

Comment: Your specification doesn't make sense. You're saying T shall be as large as L (because... same indexes) but you also give the impression that you want to throw non-positive values away. What do you want in T in the positions where L is non-positive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your **syntax is wrong** :

```
L = [1,2,-4,5,-6,7,8,9]
T = [L[i] for i in range(len(L)) if L[i]>0]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9]
```

Also you can just iterate through the elements of the list per se, no need to use a `range`. Like this : `T = [i for i in L if i>0]`

**Remember :**

When only `if` is there the syntax is `[expression for var in list if ...]`

When both `if` and `else` is there the syntax is `[expression1 if ... else expression2 for var in list]`

Comment: I believe for the `if`/`else` they syntax is `[expression1 if ... else expression2 for var in list]` which is very unlike having an `if` at the end because it doesn't leave out (skip) any iterated values.

Comment: @martineau Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You need to **write the filter after the iteration part**. So:

```
   T=[L[i] for i in range(len(L)) if L[i]>0]
#     \__/ \_______ ____________/ \___ ___/
#     yield        v                  v
#               iteration           filter
```

Right now Python thinks that you want to write a ***ternary operator***, like:

```
T=[L[i] if L[i] > 0 else 0 for i in range(len(L))]
```

This is incorrect: here you would evaluate `L[i] if L[i] > 0 else 0` for *every element*, and you would thus add a `0` for every item `L[i]` where the element is less than or equal to zero.

That being said, you can write your list comprehension more elegant (and faster), with:

```
T = [l for l in L if l > 0]
```

So instead of iterating over indices, we iterate over the *elements* `l` in `L`. We also filter on `l` and yield `l` in case the filtering is successful.

Answer (score 2):

While you can use a list comprehension to solve this problem, you can also use `filter` with a lambda function:

```
final_l = list(filter(lambda x:x > 0, L))
```